# Creating graphics in Access - Will it slow response?

Tags: ms-access

If I make up some small graphic using the rectangle control, and paste it on a form 20 times in order to make a shape, will it slow down how fast a form is loaded? Is it better to make up such graphics outside of Access and import them as a picture?

Comment: Seems to me you could test this yourself in about 5 minutes, couldn't you?

Comment: I did, and it does take longer to load. I was looking for more opinions than just my own, but I will just stick to my own observations.